# why selector is not working with Button?

Tags: android, selector, android-xml

I´m trying to make a selector for a button, it looks like:

button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryDarkColor" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryColor" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/bent2"></item>
</selector>
```

and I apply tihs in a button:

```
         <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mas"
        android:onClick="mas"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        />
```

but it doesn´t works, also the wizard mark this [image: this]

I don´t have any idea

Comment: what error is the red exclamation mark showing?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the `button_selector.xml` is inside the drawable folder.?

Comment: yes, xml file is the rigth place, when I run the project, it doesn´t mark any error, also in logcat, but doesn´t apply the style. The red exclamation only appear but it doesn´t show any warning. I don´t know if the problem is the wizard, Im using android studio 1.2.2

Comment: Does the `button_selector.xml` have the `.xml` extension in your android studio?

Comment: oh, yes, it doesn´t have the extension, it was the problem, thanks

Comment: Great.. :) Glad that it helped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension `.xml` for xml files doesnt come by default in Android Studio. Thus you have to rename your xml file as `button_selector.xml`.